# Running SQL Server stored procedure from Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I've been using this http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/SQLServer/RunStoredProcedureFromExcel.htm as a framework to try and run a stored procedure from VBA in order to pull data straight into an Excel sheet. So far, my problem is with line that's supposed to connect to SQL Server.

I currently have this:

```
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=domain\serverName;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
```

but that gives me an error that says it doesn't exist, or access is denied. I've been trying to find a better example that actually shows how I would connect to SQL Server, but haven't been able to find anything. Am I missing something obvious? Is there another way to connect to a SQL Server to run a stored procedure?

Beyond that, from looking at the code I'm not sure how the parameters for the stored procedure ever get read by the stored procedure. For example, I have two parameters, `@endDate` and `@beginDate`.

I have this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@beginDate", adDate, adParamInput, 10, Range("J3").Text)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@endDate", adDate, adParamInput, 10, Range("J4").Text)
```

but they're not used anywhere else. Is that all that's needed to connect the input from excel and the parameters in the stored procedure? I'm just trying to understand how that works.

Edit: my syntax was wrong for the database, needed more information in there. My new problem is that when creating the parameters, I get an error

> Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation.

I'm thinking that's because I'm trying to turn text into a date, where it might be better just to store it as a `varchar`? They both need to match up with a datetime column in SQL Server.

Edit2: Apparently I was wrong, because the parameters work now. Not sure why it wasn't, but it does now.

Comment: Are you using a real domain and server name? The parameter code looks right to me. A good way to get the correct connection is to create a table that points at the database, and then look at its connection properties, by right-clicking the table, choosing "Table", then choosing "Edit."

Comment: You mean opening a table in excel using the get data from sql server thing in excel? I'll try using that to see if I have the proper domain name.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks! Now just have to figure out the parameters.

Comment: Glad I could help. The parameters thing is very cool once you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to do the same thing, I found this site very helpful.
[Running a SQL Stored Procedure from Excel with Dynamic Parameters](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-with-dynamic-parameters/comment-page-2/#comment-1387999)

VBA Code will look something like this; with the Friendly Name you assign your query as "Query1" and the cells you will input the parameters in for Range.

```
Sub RefreshQuery()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query1").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = "EXECUTE dbo.StoredProcedureName '" & _
        Sheets("Parmeters").Range("J3").Value & "','" & _
        Sheets("Parmeters").Range("J4").Value & "'"
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query1").Refresh
End Sub
```

If you are using temp tables in your Stored Procedure, then make sure that you include 'SET NOCOUNT ON' at the beginning and 'SET NOCOUNT OFF' at the end of your sp.